# Missing information when Importing Contributions via API

Tags: civicontribute, api

I want to import a list of contacts from a csv file (specifically: the Contact IDs), and create a Contribution via API for each one of them. Purpose: These contacts are all ordering the same articles, but have not yet ordered via the CiviContribute system, so we need to import the data.

I wrote a PHP script for that, which is saving the new Contribution correctly on each Contact. It contains the following API call:

```
civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'create', [
        'financial_type_id' => 11,
        'receive_date' => 20201008150000,
        'total_amount' => 11.15,
        'contact_id' => $civicrm_id,
        'contribution_status_id' => "Pending", 
        'payment_instrument_id' => "Überweisung", 
        'is_pay_later' => 1,
        'price_set_id' => 25,
        'skipLineItem' => 1,
        'api.line_item.create' => [
          '0' => [
            'price_field_id' => 55,
            'qty' => 1,
            'label' => 'article name example 1',
            'line_total' => 8.57,
            'unit_price' => 8.57,
          ],
          '1' => [
            'price_field_id' => 56,
            'qty' => 1,
            'label' => 'article name example 1',
            'line_total' => 2.05,
            'unit_price' => 2.05,
          ]
        ]
      ]);
```

But it makes two mistakes:

- The value in the "Item" column in the Contribution View and the Invoice is a default value "line item". I manage to solve this by adding the article name into the code (`'label' => 'article name example 1'`), but it should be automatic.
- The tax is not added in the Contribution View and the Invoice. I think this shows that the new Contribution is not properly connected with its Financial Type (or Price Set?), because the tax is calculated automatically depending on the Financial Type, I think. I added the `'financial_type_id'` to the api Call, but the problem persists.

Any hint anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'create', [
    'financial_type_id' => 11,
    'receive_date' => 0201008150000,
    'total_amount' => 11.15,
    'tax_amount' => 0.53,
    'net_amount' => 10.62,
    'contact_id' => $civicrm_id,
    'contribution_status_id' => "Pending", 
    'payment_instrument_id' => "Überweisung", 
    'is_pay_later' => 1,
    'skipLineItem' => 1,
    'api.line_item.create' => [
        'entity_table' => 'civicrm_contribution',
        'contribution_type_id' => 11,
        'financial_type_id' => 11,
        'price_field_id' => 55,
        'label' => 'article name example 1',
        'tax_amount' => 0.53,
        'unit_price' => 10.62,
        'line_total' => 10.62,
        'non_deductible_amount' => 0.00,
        'qty' => 1.00,
      ]
  ]);
```